# Custom filter on all post page (admin backend)

Tags: posts, filters

I have a custom post type called `sales_listing`. On the All Posts page I have it showing a thumbnail column which is inserted into the postmeta table. It only creates this entry into the postmeta table if you add a thumbnail when creating the post otherwise it doesn't create the entry into the db.

What I need to do is have a dropdown filter (already have the filter showing up) that will only show the post that do not have a thumbnail image so they can be edited later on to add one. I have tried everything I can think of to no avail.

Comment: Yes, to get a precise answer it's better that you show the code you're working with. But try to reduce it to the essential: see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `restrict_manage_posts` action to add other HTML content beside the Category/Date dropdown filters. Try something simple like:

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'my_posts_restrictions' );
function my_posts_restrictions() {
    echo 'xxxxx';
}
```

This should give you xxxxx at the end of yoru filters line. Be warned, as this will appear on any Custom Post Types as well. You need to check your `current_screen` to make sure you are on the Posts list table, and not any others (like Pages for example).